# Java API evolution: how to deprecate a method accepting Object

Tags: java, api, overloading, api-design

Because of historical reasons a API I have to support contains a method

```
void item(Object id)
```

where `id` can be a numerical identification or a string alias. Since there has been confusion about which types are accepted and their semantics I wanted to provide two new methods

```
void item(CharSequence alias);
void item(int index);
```

But since I must not break downstream code I would like to provide a deprecated method retraining the old API

```
@Deprecated
void item(Object obj);
```

Now a new problem arises. The following code will call the old, deprecated method:

```
Integer index = 3;
myClass.item(index); // ← will call item(Object)
```

I'd really like to call the new method `item` in order to not have to refactor (but just recompile) the downstream code in order to not use the `@Deprecated` method. But I also do neither want to provide two methods `item(int)` and `item(Integer)` or just one method `item(Integer)` because most downstream code does work with `int`.

What is the preferred way to envolve an API like that? I thought about providing no `item(Object)` method in the default jar but provide an additional `-legacy` jar with the method. But that would impose work on downstream, too.

Comment: maybe add `item(Integer)` and mark it deprecated as well?

Comment: @kostya But that would impose calling `intValue` on downstream code instead of being able to use Java's autoboxing. Moreover, I don't see much value in adding a new deprecated method over just calling the old deprecated method. But nevertheless thanks for your suggestion, I did not think of that :)

Comment: To make myself clearer: add `item(int)` and deprecated `item(Integer)`, so the old code can slowly migrate to use `item(int)`. I know that feels hacky, but I don't think there is a better solution. Backward compatibility is hard. Beware of `item(null)` in the downstream code ;)

Comment: But what's the benefit over retaining a deprecated `item(Object)` and slowly migrating old code? Retaining `item(Object)` would also provide ABI compatibility

Comment: Actually, you are right